# chrome.bookmarks.create throws error "Cannot call method 'create' of undefined"

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Hi I want to create a very simple extension for Chrome, that will create a bookmark with a single click to a default folder. So I created an extension using this service:

http://sandbox.self.li/bookmarklet-to-extension/

Now, I have this json.manifest file

```
{
 "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
 "browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon-128.png",
 "default_title": "1ClickBookmark"
 },
 "name": "1ClickBookmark",
 "description": " - Created with http://blog.self.li",
 "homepage_url": "http://blog.self.li/post/16366939413/how-to-convert-bookmarklet-to-chrome-extension",
 "icons": {
     "16": "icon-16.png",
     "48": "icon-48.png",
     "128": "icon-128.png" },
 "permissions": [
     "tabs",
     "bookmarks",
     "http://*/*",
     "https://*/*"
 ],
 "version": "0.1",
 "manifest_version": 2
}
```

where I added "bookmarks to permission"

and the javascript file:

```
(function(){
  chrome.bookmarks.create({
  'parentId': null, 
  'title': 'AAAAAAA', 
  'url': 'http://www.google.com/'});
  alert("Bookmark added!");
})();
```

ParentId=null points to the root of "Other Bookmarks", that is fine.

The problem is that in Console I catch an exception:
**"Cannot call method 'create' of undefined" for chrome.bookmarks.create**

However, if I run just that script directly in the Background console it works just fine.
In Background console - work, in standard console - fails.

Why?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want your script to run in the context of other pages you must use [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html). As it stands, your extension is only "running" on the background page. So your background page has access to the `chrome.*` object, but other pages will not until they are injected with a content script.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to reinstall your extension after adding permission to manifest.json?

Comment: Definitely not the problem, since OP states "if I run just that script directly in the Background console it works just fine"